# Events and Independence

Tags: probability, independence

Is there any other way to check if two events $A,B$ are independent other than to verify $P(A \text{ and } B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$?

Answer (score 0):

These are some ways that came to my mind.

Suppose we are working with probability measure $P$ in a measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$.

One can alternatively show that if one sets $A'$ to be either $A$ or $\Omega \setminus A$ and $B'$ to be either $B$ or $\Omega \setminus B$ then $A$ and $B$ are independent events if and only if the condition $$P(A' \text{ and }B') = P(A')\cdot P(B')$$ is met. When we set $A'$ and $B'$ to be any combination other than $A'=A$, $B'=B$ this gives you other ways to show independence.

Aside from that, there are some events that are independent to every other event: events with probability $0$ or probability $1$. Then if either $A$ or $B$ is one of those, you will have shown $A$ and $B$ are independent.